# Eager execution disabled in Keras model on `predict_step`

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, keras, tensorflow2.0, tf.keras

Why does tensorflow disable eager execution inside the `predict_step` function of a `tf.keras.Model`? Maybe I am getting wrong something but here's an example:

```
from __future__ import annotations
from functools import wraps
import tensorflow as tf

def print_execution(func):
    @wraps(func)
    def wrapper(self: SimpleModel, data):
        print(tf.executing_eagerly())  # Prints False
        return func(self, data)
    return wrapper

class SimpleModel(tf.keras.Model):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()

    def call(self, inputs, training=None, mask=None):
        return inputs

    @print_execution
    def predict_step(self, data):
        return super().predict_step(data)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    x = tf.random.uniform((2, 2))
    print(tf.executing_eagerly())  # Prints True
    model = SimpleModel()
    pred = model.predict(x)
```

Is this the intended behavior? Is there a way to force the `predict_step` to run in eager mode?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you want to run the `predict_step` function in eager mode, you can do it as follows. Please note, it will set everything in eager mode.

```
import tensorflow as tf
tf.config.run_functions_eagerly(True)
```

Typically `tf.function` are in `Graph` mode. Using the above statement, they can be set to `Eager` mode too, [src](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/config/run_functions_eagerly).

As per your comment, AFAIK, there should not be any difference if you set `run_eagerly` while compiling the model. Here is from the official statement, [src - model.compile](https://keras.io/api/models/model_training_apis/).

> **run_eagerly**: Bool. Defaults to False. If True, this Model's logic will not be wrapped in a **tf. function**. Recommended to leave this as None unless your Model cannot be run inside a **tf. function**.

---

About your first query, why does `TensorFlow` disable eager execution inside the `predict_step` function of a `tf.keras.Model`?

One of the main reasons is to deliver the best performance of your model. And it's not only with `predict_step` but also `train_step` and `test_step`. Basically `tf. keras` models are compiled to a static graph. In order to make run them in eager mode, the above approaches need to be done. But note that, using eager mode in such cases may slow down your training. For the collective of good, `tf. keras` models are compiled in graph mode.

Comment: It seems I can also set the `self.run_eagerly = True` inside the model `__init__`, do you know if there will be a difference between both?

Comment: Updated the answer on this.

Comment: This works if the predict command is in the same file where the model is defined, but if I save the model and then in another script I load it, then the predict doesn't work. Do you know if there is a solution in this case?

Answer (score 2):

You can also set `run_eagerly = True` while compiling, this will also produce the expected result.

```
model = SimpleModel()
model.compile(run_eagerly = True)
pred = model.predict(x)
```

Results:

```
True
True
```